# Chrome box model is wrongwhen div display:table!

Tags: google-chrome, css

I made a site with simple instructions let's say:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.a120 {
background-image:url('image/back.jpg');
width:1004px;
border: 1px solid #333333;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a120">bfahksbdhabdb</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*back.jpg is 1004 pixels wide.

And then the crazy thing:

IE8, FF35, Opera9, they all show the div.a120 with a background width of 1004px that matches the width of the div and also a border of 1px on each side.

CHROME, shows me the same, at least initially.
I used a floating menu on top of the div.a120 with a width of 1004px and surprise, I realised Chrome did this to div.a120:

|-1px border          *-1002px div width-*       1px border-|

sum=1004px!!!!

Is this a normal behaviour or am I wrong?

When you use a table instead of a div with display: table the behaviour is obviously a table, but when I use display:table isn't supposed to be just a div with table vew or it becomes a table?

Thanks in advance.

A short example (change the width of the orange panel and you'll see how it covers the black border):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>gfgfg fds f sdf sdf sd fsd f sd</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0">
<div style="width:1004px; display: table;margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black">
<div style="width:967px; height:16px;background-color: #666666;border:none"><div style="width: 37px; float: right;margin-right:-37px; background-color:#ff3300">gfgfg<br />
    fds<br />
    f<br />
    sdf<br />
    sdf<br />
    sd<br />
    fsd<br />
    f<br />
    sd<br />
    ffsd<br />
    s<br />
    fsd<br />
    f<br />
    dsf<br />
    d<br />
    fsd<br />
    f</div>
dasdasdas</div>
<div style="width:967px; display:table">dasdasdas<br />
    dgf<br />
    sdf<br />
    <br />
    sdfdf<br />
    s<br />
    sdf<br />
    fds<br />
    fsd<br />
    <br />
    sdf</div>
<div style="width:967px; height:16px;">dasdasdas</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works for me - can you post a complete testcase?

Comment: Did you try using a correct doctype?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give the complete tour...

Comment: I've been cracking my head with this problem with this problem for two days. I've finally dioscovered that maybe is something without solution.

The problem is when I apply the style display:table.
When you have a <div style="width: 1004; border: 1px solid black"> you know in every browser should appear a div 1004 pixels width and a borderline of 1 pixel width. When you apply display: table, so the div would expands its height to keep with the content, then chrome changes the way it sees the div. Is a div 1002 pixels width and 1 pixel border.

I replaced the original code with an easier code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say display as a common type, it shouldn't have some hybrid fusion of inheritance, it should pick up the display properties of the type; in your case, the border width inclusion properties of a table vs a div.

Tables include the border width in the total in Chrome as opposed to a div which doesn't.

Here is a test with your code (strict doctype), a standard table and a table displaying as a div. You can see the border width inclusion differences this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>gfgfg fds f sdf sdf sd fsd f sd</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0">
    <div style="width:1004px; display: table;margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="width:967px; height:16px;background-color: #666666;border:none">
            <div style="position: relative; width: 37px; float: right;margin-right:-37px; top: 30px;background-color:#ff3300">gfgfg<br />
                sdf<br />
                f<br />
            </div>
        Div Displaying as table
        </div>
        <div style="width:967px; display:table">dasdasdas<br />
            dgf<br />
            <br />
            sdf</div>
        <div style="width:967px; height:16px;">dasdasdas</div>
    </div>

    <table style="width:1004px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; height:16px;background-color: #666666;border:none">
                <div style="position: relative; top: 10px;width: 37px; float: right;margin-right:-37px; background-color:#ff3300">gfgfg<br />
                    ds<br />
                    f<br />
                    sdf<br />
                </div>
                Table displaying as a table
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; display:table">dasdasdas<br />
                dgf<br />
                sdf<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; height:16px;">dasdasdas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width:1004px; display: block;margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; height:16px;background-color: #666666;border:none">
                <div style="position: relative; top: 10px;width: 37px; float: right;margin-right:-37px; background-color:#ff3300">gfgfg<br />
                    asd<br />
                    f<br />
                    sdf<br />
                </div>
                Table displaying as block
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; display:table">dasdasdas<br />
                dgf<br />
                sdf<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:967px; height:16px;">dasdasdas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: - If you use strict you shouldn't use <br />, it triggers the quirks mode. -

I see what you did but my problem is with the orange block.
I positioned OK in FF35, IE8, IE7 and IE6, but Chrome leaks sideways.

I'm not using tables, is a seo design with a big orange column at the right, I think I should use your "relative" example as a way to solve it, but I don't know if the right orange column will keep with the left contents.

Sorry if I'm being cryptic with the example but the site I'm working on it is not online, so I can't give anymore clues.

I'll do a home sample for you to see. Thanks!!

Comment: Kwek!!!
My mistake, I give your data a thoroughful look and found some answers, if it works as I expected I'll thank you forever... :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, lemme know if it helped.

Comment: I must say, that same thing happend in my Chrome. It updated to 16.xx and when I refreshed page `display: table;` for some reason sorted everything into two columns.